# XpsDocument GetFixedDocumentSequence return null

Tags: c#, printing, tcpclient, xps

I read data from printer like this:

```
  using (Stream stream = client.GetStream())
  {
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
      stream.CopyTo(ms);

      client.Close();

      byte[] result = ms.ToArray();
      ...

     using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(result))
     {
      using (var package = Package.Open(memoryStream, FileMode.Open))
      {
        var packageUri = new Uri("memorystream://printstream");
        PackageStore.AddPackage(packageUri, package);
        var xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(package, CompressionOption.Fast, packageUri.OriginalString);
        return xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence() // NULL
```

I tried also saving stream directly to the file and then read as File.ReadAllBytes(filePath), but result is the same.

After I save stream to the file I can open it via XpsViewer without any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange but it's working. I have to used XpsConverter.exe and convert .xps file to .xps. Here is @AXMIM [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35438631/xpsdocument-getfixeddocumentsequence-return-null-for-files-generated-by-a-specif)